# How can I calculate the remaining amount per row?

Tags: sql

I have a table that I want to find for each row id the amount remaining from the total. However, the order of amounts is in an ascending order.

```
id   amount
1    3
2    2
3    1
4    5
```

The results should look like this:

```
id   remainder
1    10
2    8
3    5
4    0
```

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this? I'm guessing that the over clause is the way to go, but I can't quite piece it together.Thanks.

Comment: Please add a tag that identifies the specific rdbms your using

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 answer, I can't provide an SQL Fiddle, it seems it strips the `begin` keyword, resulting to syntax errors. I tested this on my machine though:

```
create function RunningTotalGuarded()
returns @ReturnTable table(
    Id int, 
    Amount int not null, 
    RunningTotal int not null, 
    RN int identity(1,1) not null primary key clustered
)

as
begin

  insert into @ReturnTable(id, amount, RunningTotal) 
  select id, amount, 0 from tbl order by amount;

  declare @RunningTotal numeric(16,4) = 0;
  declare @rn_check int = 0;

  update @ReturnTable
    set 
        @rn_check = @rn_check + 1
        ,@RunningTotal = 
        case when rn = @rn_check then
            @RunningTotal + Amount
        else
            1 / 0
        end
        ,RunningTotal = @RunningTotal;     
  return;    
end;
```

To achieve your desired output:

```
with a as
(
    select *, sum(amount) over() - RunningTotal as remainder
        , row_number() over(order by id) as id_order
    from RunningTotalGuarded()
)
select a.id, amount_order.remainder
from a
inner join a amount_order on amount_order.rn = a.id_order;
```

Rationale for guarded running total: http://www.ienablemuch.com/2012/05/recursive-cte-is-evil-and-cursor-is.html

Choose the lesser evil ;-)

Comment: I'll take it into consideration. Thank you for showing me this. I do want to know, how would I accomplish this if I wanted to use the cursor and break up the totals by another id in the table?

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't specify your RDBMS, I will just assume it's Postgresql ;-)

```
select  *, sum(amount) over() - sum(amount) over(order by amount) as remainder
from tbl;
```

Output:

```
| ID | AMOUNT | REMAINDER |
---------------------------
|  3 |      1 |        10 |
|  2 |      2 |         8 |
|  1 |      3 |         5 |
|  4 |      5 |         0 |
```

How it works: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/c446a/5

It works in SQL Server 2012 too: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c446a/1

Thinking of solution for SQL Server 2008...

---

Btw, is your ID just a mere row number? If it is, just do this:

```
select 
  row_number() over(order by amount) as rn
  , sum(amount) over() - sum(amount) over(order by amount) as remainder
from tbl
order by rn;
```

Output:

```
| RN | REMAINDER |
------------------
|  1 |        10 |
|  2 |         8 |
|  3 |         5 |
|  4 |         0 |
```

But if you really need the ID intact and move the smallest amount on top, do this:

```
with a as
(
  select  *, sum(amount) over() - sum(amount) over(order by amount) as remainder,
      row_number() over(order by id) as id_sort,
      row_number() over(order by amount) as amount_sort
  from tbl
)
select a.id, sort.remainder
from a
join a sort on sort.amount_sort = a.id_sort
order by a.id_sort;
```

Output:

```
| ID | REMAINDER |
------------------
|  1 |        10 |
|  2 |         8 |
|  3 |         5 |
|  4 |         0 |
```

See query progression here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c446a/11

Comment: I actually left out one more specification: I am sorting these amounts by an outside key. There would be another integer id to divide them up by. Critical to forget I know, but being able to use it in a CTE solves another part of my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to offer a simpler way to do this in descending order:

```
select id, sum(amount) over (order by id desc) as Remainder
from t
```

This will work in Oracle, SQL Server 2012, and Postgres.

The general solution requres a self join:

```
select t.id, coalesce(sum(tafter.amount), 0) as Remainder
from t left outer join
     t tafter
     on t.id < tafter.id
group by t.id
```

Comment: Running total on 100 rows is equal to 5,050 spinning of hard disk platters. For 1,000 rows, it's more exponential, it is equal to 500,500 spinning of hard disk platters ;-) http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/07/12/running-sums-redux.aspx

Comment: @MichaelBuen . . . Yes, I agree.  All database vendors should include support for the full range of window functions.

Comment: Say if I wanted to sort by another id on the table, would using the where clause divide it up for me or do I have to partition by that id value?

Comment: @user1281598 . . . In the first version, if you just want to change the id, that's the order by.  If you wanted to start over again for different groups of records, say countries, you would add a partition clause.  In the second version, you would add an "=" clause to the join.